# Difference between specifications of fread and fgets?

Tags: c, fgets, fread

What is the difference between fread and fgets when reading in from a file?
I use the same fwrite statement, however when I use fgets to read in a .txt file it works as intended, but when I use fread() it does not.

I've switched from fgets/fputs to fread/fwrite when reading from and to a file. I've used fopen(rb/wb) to read in binary rather than standard characters. I understand that fread will get /0 Null bytes as well rather than just single lines.

```
  //while (fgets(buff,1023,fpinput) != NULL) //read in from file
  while (fread(buff, 1, 1023, fpinput) != 0) // read from file
```

I expect to read in from a file to a buffer, put the buffer in shared memory, and then have another process read from shared memory and write to a new file.

When I use fgets() it works as intended with .txt files, but when using fread it adds a single line from 300~ characters into the buffer with a new line. Can't for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: `fgets` stops reading when it encounted a line feed. `fread` doesn't check for those.

Comment: `fgets` adds a NUL. `fread` doesn't.

Comment: Did you treat the buf as a NUL-terminated string when it wasn't?

Comment: Really?? fread reads a specified number of (raw binary) bytes, while fgets reads a text line up to end-of-line char. And appends null. You can use fread on text files, but fgets on binary usually isn't a good idea. Don't skip your C lectures ;)

Comment: I'm trying to convert it all to only using fread()/fwrite(). But when I use fgets it results in : https://prnt.sc/neq45x But when I use fread() it results in: https://prnt.sc/neq4bz

Comment: When you use `fread` you must remember and use the number of units read, not just check for `0`. But `fread` isn't very useful for a text file unless you just want to copy it unprocessed into another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets` will stop when encountering a newline. `fread` does not. So `fgets` is typically only useful for text files, while `fread` can be used for both text and binary files.

From the C11 standard:

[7.21.7.2 The fgets function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.2)

> The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by s. No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

[7.21.8.1 The fread function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.8.1)

> The fread function reads, into the array pointed to by ptr, up to nmemb elements whose size is specified by size, from the stream pointed to by stream. For each object, size calls are made to the fgetc function and the results stored, in the order read, in an array of unsigned char exactly overlaying the object. The file position indicator for the stream (if defined) is advanced by the number of characters successfully read. If an error occurs, the resulting value of the file position indicator for the stream is indeterminate. If a partial element is read, its value is indeterminate.

This snippet maybe will make things clearer for you. It just copies a file in chunks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if(argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: ./a.out src dst\n");
        printf("Copies file src to dst\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    const size_t chunk_size = 1024;

    FILE *in, *out;
    if(! (in = fopen(argv[1], "rb"))) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if(! (out = fopen(argv[2], "wb"))) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    char * buffer;
    if(! (buffer = malloc(chunk_size))) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    size_t bytes_read;

    do {
        // fread returns the number of successfully read elements
        bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, chunk_size, in);

        /* Insert any modifications you may */
        /* want to do here                  */

        // write bytes_read bytes from buffer to output file
        if(fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, out) != bytes_read) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   // When we read less than chunk_size we are either done or an error has 
   // occured. This error is not handled in this program. 
    } while(bytes_read == chunk_size); 


    free(buffer);
    fclose(out);
    fclose(in);
}
```

You mentioned in a comment below that you wanted to use this for byteswapping. Well, you can just use the following snippet. Just insert it where indicated in code above.

```
for(int i=0; i < bytes_read - bytes_read%2; i+=2) {
    char tmp = buffer[i];
    buffer[i] = buffer[i+1];
    buffer[i+1] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Must I use size_t buff[1024] type when working with bytes rather than char buff[1024] ? My end goal with this program is to do a simple swap of bytes where abcdef becomes -> badcfe. Then I wish to run the program again to swap it back. It should be able to work on .txt and .png files. That's why I'm starting with the easier .txt before tackling .png. I figured since chars are a single byte in memory it should work? @Broman

Comment: @RemiliaScarlet I'm not sure what you mean here. The buffer is of type `char*`. If your goal is binary files, you should start with binary files. The procedure is basically the same, but the tools are very different and if it works on binary files it will also work on text files. After all, text files is a subset of binary files.

Comment: Ah my mistake, and yes my problem is I'm not familiar with the new tools required to do it with binary rather than strings. I'll continue to mess with it.

Comment: @RemiliaScarlet Feel free to use the code above. It seems like you could use it as it is. Just insert your modification code where I have indicated it above.

Comment: I'm messing with it now, this does work to copy in data and write it out, I just tried it with a png and it did it correctly, same with .txt. I will make this work! Thanks a ton for the help I've been messing with this for the last 10~ hours haha

Comment: @RemiliaScarlet It's so easy when you know how to do it. ;) I created a byte swapping snippet and added it to the answer, so there you have that too.